# Vscode How to hide top bar with file/directory/app file?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

How to remove top panel where file/directory/app file/etc. is written? Like in image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmB4H.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Found it, just press F11